# Building bar graph from SCCM report

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, sccm

I want to make a graph in Report Builder using my SCCM script that will show files like "%.DOCX, %.PST, %.XLSX, etc." I know it must have something to do with editing the line "SF.FileName" and making it group those files together and listing them simply as the extension, I just don't know how it should look like, if it should be in group expression or filter? So it looks like the X axis will show the file types and the Y axis will show number of files. Here is my report script:

> Select Distinct SYS.Netbios_Name0, SYS.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0, SF.FileName, SF.FileDescription, SF.FileVersion, SF.FileSize, SF.FileModifiedDate, SF.FilePath from fn_rbac_GS_SoftwareFile(@UserSIDs) SF LEFT JOIN fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs) SYS on SF.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID WHERE SYS.Netbios_Name0 Like @variable AND SF.FilePath Like 'E:\Home-Folders\%' Order by SF.FileName

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

As you said, we need to get the X axis, Y axis first.

The following query can give you some inspiration:

```
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN FILENAME LIKE '%.EXE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '%.exe',
SUM(CASE WHEN FILENAME LIKE '%.INI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '%.ini'
FROM v_GS_SoftwareFile
```

Then you could refer to the tutorial to fill up the bar chart.

[Tutorial: Add a Bar Chart to Your Report (Report Builder)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255225.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I've gone as far as creating the bar graph. My current situation now has to do with labels and FilePath. I am very new to SSRS so I don't know how to do many things. The tutorial doesn't help with creating the right kind of labels I'd like. I just don't know what kind of expression to use. I assume it should be something like "if string equals %.doc then display as 'doc'", but I don't know the syntax. Also I'm trying to figure out how to make the bar graph tie in with my FilePath parameter, if I search for files in the G:\, I'd like it to show on both the bar and pie graph.

Comment: Any help on this, anyone?